# reading from a file(whose contents are copied from another file) in java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

i am reading from a text file(a file in which i wrote some sentences) and printing its contents everything was going well until i copied the same sentences from a PDF file, then nothing is printed into the console ,giving me build successful.

this is my code:

```
        File f=new File("input.txt");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            int i=0;
            while ( i< line.length()) 
            {
                char c=line.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(c);
                i++;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
```

the contents of the text file (whether when i write the sentences by myself or copy it from the PDF):

```
{sample program in TINY language- computes factorial}
read x;{input an integer}
if 0<x then {don’t compute if x<=0}
fact:=1;
repeat
fact:=fact*x;
x:=x-1
```

what am i doing wrong and what to do if i wanted to copy sentences from a PDF file into the text file i am reading from

Comment: Change `sc.hasNext()` to `sc.hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extract text or other information from pdf file use `Oracle's` library `PDFBox`.

[PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) is the best library for this purpose, it's comprehensive and really quite easy to use if you're just doing basic text extraction.

Answer (score 0):

It's working well for me, I even created a pdf from your text input and I copied the text back to a .txt file and it still working. I used Notepad++ to create my .txt file.